# Oracle PLSQL CreateSchemaBasedXML using multiple schemas

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to perform XSD validation against an XML document within PLSQL and I'm having an issue with getting it working.

I have created an `XMLTYPE` object, which when I call `isSchemaBased()` against it returns 0 (false). Now obviously the `XMLTYPE` needs to be schema based in order to be validated, I found that you can make a schema based version by calling `createSchemaBasedXML` against the `XMLTYPE`. The problem I am having is that my schema is broken into two parts (combining the schema files is not an option unfortunately), which means that when I try and `createSchemaBasedXML` specifying the main schema it fails because it is unable to resolve a reference which is imported from the second XSD document.

```
-- lxml is the XMLTYPE which has been populated with the XML before this point

dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(
  schemaURL => mainSchemaURL,
  schemaDoc => mainSchemaDoc,
  local => true,
  genTypes => true,
  genTables => false,
  force => true,
  enableHierarchy => dbms_xmlschema.ENABLE_HIERARCHY_NONE);

dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema(
  schemaURL => importedSchemaURL,
  schemaDoc => importedSchemaDoc,
  local => true,
  genTypes => true,
  genTables => false,
  force => true,
  enableHierarchy => dbms_xmlschema.ENABLE_HIERARCHY_NONE);

if lxml.isSchemaBased() = 1 then
  dbms_output.put_line('Schema based');
else
  dbms_output.put_line('Non-schema based');
end if;

dbms_ouput.put_line('About to apply schema');
lxml := lxml.createSchemaBasedXML(mainSchemaURL);
dbms_ouput.put_line('We don't get this far');

lxml := lxml.createSchemaBasedXML(importedSchemaURL);
```

Is there any way of being able to import both the `mainSchemaURL` and the `importedSchemaURL` at the same time so that the imported schema references within the main schema don't cause the failure;

`ORA-31079: unable to result reference to type [type containing imported type]`

Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:** I am working with Oracle version 11g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was provided by 'odie_63' on the Oracle forums [here][1]
In the end it was a case of specifying the schemaLocation for the import of the importedSchema

[1]: https://forums.oracle.com/message/11135111 "CreateSchemaBasedXML using multiple schemas 
"